# Significato di "far ventre" in questa frase

Tags: meaning

Leggendo il romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, mi sono imbattuta in la frase seguente, in cui appare l'espressione "far ventre" (grassetto mio):

> La tramvia passava con la gente stipata ordinatamente a **far ventre** in quel dentro.

Non capisco cosa significa questa espressione. L'ho cercata alla voce "ventre" di alcuni dizionari, ma non l'ho trovata. Tuttavia, ne ho trovato un esempio di uso al lemma "ventritogato" del [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000763.jpg) (*Martinozzi*
 [in *Carducci*, III-25-116]):

> Lascia il barbaro metro, onde  si  sdegna  
>    la  viva  Italia  e  il  vate  suo  rimpiange; 
>   lascia i  fratelli  Asvini  e  la  falange  
>   ventri-togata  e  che  a  far  ventre insegna.

Allora, vi chiedo: qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare cosa vuol dire "far ventre" nella frase sopra citata?

Comment: Penso si riferisca metaforicamente ad un ventre che contiene tutta la gente stipata sul tram.

Comment: @Gio secondo me hai ragione; fare ventre =  ingrassare, ingrossare, far divenire grosso.

Comment: Curioso... [Qui](http://www.gruppodeiromanisti.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/1954-intero.pdf), a p. 70, c'è qualche informazione su questi versi, che furono inviati a Carducci da un anonimo che si firmava “G.M.” (cioè forse il Martinozzi lì citato?), e Carducci stesso commenta “Quando il signor G. M. a suo comodo mi avrà spiegato che cosa intenda per _falange ventritogata e che a far ventre insegna_, vedrò se sarà il caso di lasciarla”. Non so se si riferisse specificamente a “far ventre”, ma in ogni caso tutta l'espressione non doveva essere troppo limpida neppure nel suo contesto.